# Why does k-NN algorithm produce different predictions with same model and data?

Tags: k-nearest-neighbour, randomness

I have successfully created a model using Apple coremltools' [KNearestNeighborsClassifierBuilder()](https://coremltools.readme.io/docs/updatable-nearest-neighbor-classifier) and trained it. However, each time I run the algorithm, I get different predictions. Here are the predictions from two consecutive runs:

```
{
output: "label4"
outputProbs: {
    label1 = "5.473199179217296e-07";
    label2 = 0;
    label3 = "2.067466368542379e-07";
    label4 = "0.9999982122014233";
    label5 = "9.303587035568537e-07";
}

{
output: "label1"
outputProbs: {
    label1 = "0.5177690637938742";
    label2 = 0;
    label3 = "0.08037182270102097";
    label4 = "0.3616732021545944";
    label5 = 0;
}
```

As you see, both the predicted labels and the predicted probabilities differs.

To make sure I use the same model for each prediction, I printed the models' hash, and the hashes are the same:

```
updateableModel.hash: 105553173700032
updateableModel.hash: 105553173700032
```

I have also printed the inputs from each prediction, to make sure I provide the model with the same data:

```
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2.199277968312546,0,0,0,0,0]
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2.199277968312546,0,0,0,0,0]
```

As far as I know, k-nearest neighbors only introduces randomness when there are ties (two or more labels with the same predicted probabilities). However, that is not the case here.

Here is the Python code used to create the model:

```python
from coremltools.models.nearest_neighbors import KNearestNeighborsClassifierBuilder
from coremltools.models import MLModel

# Create the model.
builder = KNearestNeighborsClassifierBuilder(input_name='input',
   output_name='output',
   number_of_dimensions=18,
   default_class_label='unknown',
   number_of_neighbors=20,
   weighting_scheme='inverse_distance',
   index_type='linear')

# Save the model.
mlmodel_updatable = MLModel(builder.spec)
mlmodel_updatable.save('output/MyModel.mlmodel')
```

Here is the Swift code used to run the model:

```swift
func predict() {
    print("predict()")

    let updateableModelURL = try! FileManager.default
        .url(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
        .appendingPathComponent("MyModel.mlmodelc")

    let config = MLModelConfiguration()
    config.computeUnits = .all

    do {
        let updateableModel = try MLModel(contentsOf: updateableModelURL, configuration: config)

        let tfidfVector = tfidfVectorizer(input: "fixed string")

        print("tfidfVector: \(tfidfVector)")

        let predictions = try updateableModel.prediction(from: MyModelInput(input: tfidfVector))

        print("predictions: \(predictions.featureValue(for: "outputProbs"))")
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Here is the output from calling the `predict()` function twice using a button:

```
predict()
tfidfVector: Double 18 vector
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2.199277968312546,0,0,0,0,0]
predictions: Optional(Dictionary : {
    label1 = "5.473199179217296e-07";
    label2 = 0;
    label3 = "2.067466368542379e-07";
    label4 = "0.9999982122014233";
    label5 = "9.303587035568537e-07";
})

predict()
tfidfVector: Double 18 vector
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2.199277968312546,0,0,0,0,0]
predictions: Optional(Dictionary : {
    label1 = "0.5177690637938742";
    label2 = 0;
    label3 = "0.08037182270102097";
    label4 = "0.3616732021545944";
    label5 = 0;
})
```

Each time I call `predict()`, I get new results. Why do I get different predictions each time?

PS: I have also tried to load the model and set `updateableModel` using `MLModel()` only once outside the `predict()` function, but the result is still different predictions each time.

EDIT: Here is the predicted probability for one of the labels for some consecutive runs. Sometimes, the predicted probabilities are the same two times in a row. It also sometimes reproduces the same predicted probabilities several times (e.g. `0.6529152614294412` which appears several times):

```
0.6225963954316593
0.6225963954316593
0.5766789368130426
0.5517395578015007
0.6529152614294412
0.6529152614294412
0.4972722062412557
0.6529152614294412
0.6225963954316593
0.5517395578015007
0.5766789368130426
0.6529152614294412
0.5517395578015007
0.6529152614294412
0.6225963954316593
0.5517395578015007
0.6225963954316593
0.6529152614294412
0.6225963954316593
0.6529152614294412
0.4972722062412557
0.5766789368130426
0.6529152614294412
0.5517395578015007
0.6529152614294412
0.6225963954316593
0.5281772667256046
0.6336796983066627
0.5281772667256046
0.5496822251293079
```

Comment: Can you share your code as well?

Comment: I have now added the Python code used to create the model.

Comment: what is your usage look like for the two runs? I wonder if you use the same object twice.

Comment: I have now added the Swift code used to run the model. As you see, I load it from the same path.

Comment: Are there ties in the *input* of the reference data? If yes, then the algo might choose different neighbours by chance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Michael M pointed out, there were ties in the *input* data used to train the model. Removing the ties, solved the issue. Researching the issue of ties in *k*-NN, I found the article [Breaking Ties in K-NN Classification](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/breaking-ties-k-nn-classification-nicholas-pylypiw/) for anyone interested.